# useState does not set value in react under `useCallBack`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have one local variable that is controlled by `useState` that should be set after calling useCallback. However, after debug I do not see the `info` is set. Looking for different solution in stackoverflow. but still do not know how to fix it

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState<object>({});
  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(info);//{}
    setInfo({ name: "name1", address: "1234" });
    console.log(info);//{}
  }, [info]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That second `console.log()` will not have the new value at that time.  It has to wait for the batched update that React does under the hood.

Comment: Add a debugging `useEffect(() => console.log(info), [info])` to make sure it changes.